# Unknow reason for invalid syntax

Tags: python, api, weather

I do not understand why I receive an "invalid syntax" error. I did an hour of research with no success. I am running PYTHON 3. Where is the syntax error in this code?

```
  from urllib.request import urlopen
  import json

  request = urlopen("http://api.aerisapi.com/observations/Urbandale,IA?client_id=QD2ToJ2o7MKAX47vrBcsC&client_secret=0968kxX4DWybMkA9GksQREwBlBlC4njZw9jQNqdO")
  response = request.read().decode("utf-8")
  json = json.loads(response)
  if json['success']:
      ob = json['respnose']['ob']
      print ("the current weather in urbandale is %s with a temperature of %d") % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF']
 else
      print "An error occurred: %s" % (json['error']['description'])
 request().close
```

Comment: Have you at least read [wikipedia python syntax summary page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics)?

Comment: i use wiki books but not wikipedia thats what i was taught in school dont use wilikpediea

Comment: and I use official documentation and mailing lists, that what I've learnt from professional career. :) But even wikipedia knowledge would suffice to fix this :)

Comment: This question does not even include the error message encountered.

Comment: it does to it has invaild syntax thats the only error there is no track back error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several reasons:

1. Your parenthesis are not balanced:

   ```
   print ("the current weather in urbandale is %s with a temperature of %d") % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF']
   ```

   That's one closing parenthesis missing, and the one you have is in the wrong position.

   This should be:

   ```
   print ("the current weather in urbandale is %s with a temperature of %d" % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF']))
   ```
2. Your `else` statement is missing the `:` colon.
3. Your second `print` function is not a function, it pretends to be a Python 2 statement instead. Correct it by adding parenthesis:

   ```
   print("An error occurred: %s" % (json['error']['description']))
   ```
4. Your indentation appears to be incorrect, but that could be a posting error.
5. Your last line is not valid either; you want to call `close()`, not `request()`:

   ```
   request.close()
   ```

   With `urllib`, you don't need to close the object, really.
6. You misspelled `respnose`:

   ```
   ob = json['response']['ob']
   ```

Working code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

request = urlopen("http://api.aerisapi.com/observations/Urbandale,IA?client_id=QD2ToJ2o7MKAX47vrBcsC&client_secret=0968kxX4DWybMkA9GksQREwBlBlC4njZw9jQNqdO")
response = request.read().decode("utf-8")
json = json.loads(response)
if json['success']:
    ob = json['response']['ob']
    print("the current weather in urbandale is %s with a temperature of %d" % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF']))
else:
    print("An error occurred: %s" % (json['error']['description']))
```

Comment: @apples723: That's because Python cannot know when the closing parenthesis will come and only misses it when you start the `else:` line.

Comment: ok i no longer get syntax error only this raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/sddf.py", line 8, in <module>
    ob = json['respnose']['ob']
KeyError: 'respnose'

Comment: @apples723: see my point 6.

Comment: omg your a life savor i've been trying to get a working script since sunday now its thursday thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need a `:` after `else`;

```
else:
      print "An error occurred: %s" % (json['error']['description'])
```

Number of `(` and `)` on this line are not equal:

```
>>> strs = """print ("the current weather in urbandale is %s with a temperature of %d") % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF']"""
>>> strs.count('(')
3
>>> strs.count(')')
2
```

`if-else` should be properly indented like this:

```
if json['success']:
    ob = json['respnose']['ob']
    print ("the current weather in urbandale is %s with a temperature of %d") % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF'])
else:
    print "An error occurred: %s" % (json['error']['description'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
print ("the current weather in urbandale is %s with a temperature of %d") % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF']
```

is missing a closing `)`

It should be

```
print ("the current weather in urbandale is %s with a temperature of %d" % (ob['weather'].lower(), ob['tempF']))
```

Python would probably be complaining about it in the *next* line

Comment: ok i changed it and get this raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/sddf.py", line 8, in <module>
    ob = json['respnose']['ob']
KeyError: 'respnose'